# Creating external table on hive via elasticsearch gives permission issue

Tags: elasticsearch, hive

`Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: HiveAccessControlException Permission denied: user [ab_user] does not have [RWSTORAGE] privilege on [esstoragehandler://upsert/<ES server ip>/<index key>/<index name>/<ES Port>/false/] (state=42000,code=40000)`

I get the above error while I try creating elasticsearch index from hive external table. Can you help me from which side this problem needs to be solved and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to upgrade of Apache version, which required another access from hive while moving data from hive to elasticsearch. Ask concern hive team to provide the access.